# How to translate 0V pulldown switch to negative voltage?

Tags: cmos, flipflop, level-shifting, resistor-transistor-logic

I have a circuit with a momentary switch connected between GND and a net with a pullup resistor (switch output is 0V while pressed). This switch signal is then buffered by a flip-flop before feeding additional CMOS circuitry. I had this circuit working nicely, but now need to change the supply voltages for the flip flop & CMOS to use a bipolar supply (+6V/-6V) instead of the (12V/0V) used previously. Additionally, I still need the momentary switch to switch 0V, rather than -6V.
Ideally, the phase should be unchanged. I am struggling to come up with a simple transistor-logic level-shifter to accomplish this goal.

The image attached below shows my working circuit before updating the supply voltages. The other half of the flip-flop here is powered by a 12V/0V supply, but I want to change this to +6V/-6V.
The switch pin to GND must remain unchanged, but any other modifications are acceptable to allow for level shifting to +6V/-6V logic signals to/from the flip-flop.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image: existing circuit before updating supply voltages]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If the switch remains pulling the input to GND, half-way between the two new logic rails, there is no way to do this with only one transistor while maintaining the switch signal logic polarity.  With two transistors there are lotsa configurations that will work.  Since you are not using the Set input, is moving the input signal to Set an acceptable option?  This changes the logic polarity, so now a 1-transistor input converter will work.

Comment: Thanks @AnalogKid - that solution probably would have worked as well. However, the other supplied answer also works great! I'll probably end up going with the single N-ch MOSFET solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the switch to the gate of an N-channel MOSFET between the switch and the pullup.  Pull the gate and source to -V and let the drain operate the flip-flop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffpeGS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This approach inverts the logic polarity of the control signal, something the OP does not want.

Comment: I don't believe so.  When the switch is closed, the signal to the FF will be low, just as it was in the single-supply version.  The difference is that the switch to ground is now a pull-up instead of a pull-down, so the change in the switch polarity is countered by the inversion of the FET.

Comment: Got me.  Nice one.